# How to scan 2D barcodes in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, zxing, flutter-web

I have an application, written in flutter, that is heavily dependent on the feature of scanning pdf-417 type codes. In the Android port, it works easily, using the qr_code_scanner 0.0.13 library from pub.dev. I need a web application, for various reasons, and I want to implement the scanning functionality in it. I have tried searching librarys that support the web also, but couldn't find anything relevant. I tried creating a html/js scanner webpage, with zxing-js, that works in a normal browser, but not in the flutter webview, which uses the easy_web_view pub.dev package. It seems from the errors, that it cannot access the camera. What should be the easiest way of solving this? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Will [this](https://medium.com/@mk.pyts/how-to-access-webcam-video-stream-in-flutter-for-web-1bdc74f2e9c7) be helpful ?

Comment: Did any find a solution for a 2D barcode scanner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/ai_barcode) that support `web`, `android` and `IOS` in flutter.
Also see this [link](https://github.com/pdliuw/flutter_app_sample/blob/master/lib/component/barcode/app_barcode_scanner_widget.dart)